# Cannot destructure property using useSelector in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I have tried to persist redux state with **redux-persist**, as I am new to redux I don't know which thing I am missing. I am trying to destruct state variable but it shows the error:

```
Login.jsx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isSuccess' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Login (Login.jsx:13:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25sjsj850:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:1)
```

Here is a userSlice.js file code,

```
const userToken = localStorage.getItem("token")
  ? localStorage.getItem("token")
  : null;

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    userInfo: {},
    userToken,
    isFetching: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
    errorMessage: "",
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [otp_verify.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = false;
      state.userInfo = payload.phone;
      state.userToken = payload.token;
      return state;
    },
    [otp_verify.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.isSuccess = null;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = null;
    },
    [otp_verify.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.errorMessage = payload.message;
      return state;
    },
    [signupUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = false;
      state.phone = payload.phone;
      return state;
    },
    [signupUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.isSuccess = null;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = null;
    },
    [signupUser.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.errorMessage = payload.message;
      return state;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = false;
      state.phone = payload.phone;
      return state;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, { error }) => {
      console.log("payload", error);
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.errorMessage = error.message;
      return state;
    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.isSuccess = null;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = null;
    },
    [fetchUserBytoken.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.isSuccess = null;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = null;
    },
    [fetchUserBytoken.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = false;
      state.phone = payload.phone;
      return state;
    },
    [fetchUserBytoken.rejected]: (state, { error }) => {
      console.log("fetchUserBytoken");
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.errorMessage = error.message;
      return state;
    },
    [logout.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = false;
      state.userToken = null;
      return state;
    },
    [logout.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.isSuccess = null;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.isError = null;
    },
    [logout.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.errorMessage = payload.message;
      return state;
    },
  },
});

// export const { clearState } = userSlice.actions;
const { reducer } = userSlice;
export default reducer;
```

And I have used redux-perist in this store.js file,

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/user/userSlice";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

I am trying to destruct variable in Login.js file as below,

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../features/user/userSlice";

const Login = () => {
  const [phn, setPhn] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isSuccess, isError, errorMessage } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.user
  );
```

I have tried to figure out what the problem is, but couldn't find it. Can someone please help?